# allocating score based on values in columns

Tags: r

```
MY_CARS_SALES <- data.frame(
  AGE = c(2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 5),
  ANTIQUE= c("YES", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES", "NO"),
  SMOKE= c(2,0,1,3,0,1), 
  PRICE = c(45, 40, 6, 22, 16, 10), 
  TOYOTA = c(5, 9, 8, 9, 2, 3), 
 VOLVO = c(7, 6, 4, 10, 12, 8),
  MERC = c(2, 12, 1, 7, 8, 3),
  MAZDA = c(9, 2, 4, 6, 13, 6),
  NISSAN = c(1, 3, 23, 7, 12, 2),
  HONDA = c(2, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4),
  VW = c(4, 12, 7, 9, 5, 1),
  ROVER = c(1,3, 2, 4, 3, 1))
```

Hello, hope you are all good. I have a df like this, and I want to tell R to look at some columns. For values (in VOLVO and VW) that is less than the Median, give a score of 1 (otherwise, score 0). For values (in NISSAN and ROVER) that is greater than median, score 1 (otherwise, score 0). Score 1 if the value in ‘SMOKE’ is ‘0’ (otherwise, score zero). Also, score 1 if the value in ‘PRICE’ is between  6 and 16 (otherwise score 0), and score 1 if value in ANTIQUE is "YES"
Then, finally, add up all those scores under a new column (SCORE).
I have included my code below, which does not run as I thought it would. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here.
Any suggestions please.

```
MY_CARS_SALES$NEWSCORE <- rowSums(cbind(
sapply(MY_CARS_SALES[c("VOLVO" , "VW")], function(x){ifelse(x < median(x), 1, 0)}),
sapply(MY_CARS_SALES[c("NISSAN", "ROVER")], function(x){ifelse(x > median(x), 1, 0)}),
sapply(MY_CARS_SALES["SMOKE"], function(x) {ifelse(x == '0', 1, 0)}),
sapply(MY_CARS_SALES["PRICE"], function(x) {ifelse(x == '6:10', 1, 0)}),
sapply(MY_CARS_SALES["ANTIQUE"], function(x) {ifelse(x == 'YES', 1, 0)})))
```

Comment: For example, for VOLVO and VW, does both should be less than median or give score for each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For minimal difference with your code,

```
MY_CARS_SALES$NEWSCORE <- rowSums(cbind(
  sapply(MY_CARS_SALES[c("VOLVO" , "VW")], function(x){ifelse(x<median(x), 1, 0)}),
  sapply(MY_CARS_SALES[c("NISSAN", "ROVER")],function(x){ifelse(x>median(x), 1, 0)}),
  sapply(MY_CARS_SALES["SMOKE"], function(x){ifelse(x == '0', 1, 0)}),
  sapply(MY_CARS_SALES["PRICE"], function(x){ifelse(x %in% c(6:16), 1, 0)}),
  sapply(MY_CARS_SALES["ANTIQUE"], function(x){ifelse(x == 'YES', 1, 0)})))
```

only change `"PRICE"` line from `ifelse(x == '6:10', 1, 0)` to `ifelse(x %in% c(6:16), 1, 0)` and `NEWSCORE` is `c(3, 3, 3, 2, 6, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

## Data

```
MY_CARS_SALES <- data.frame(
  AGE = c(2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 5),
  ANTIQUE= c("YES", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES", "NO"),
  SMOKE= c(2,0,1,3,0,1), 
  PRICE = c(45, 40, 6, 22, 16, 10), 
  TOYOTA = c(5, 9, 8, 9, 2, 3), 
  VOLVO = c(7, 6, 4, 10, 12, 8),
  MERC = c(2, 12, 1, 7, 8, 3),
  MAZDA = c(9, 2, 4, 6, 13, 6),
  NISSAN = c(1, 3, 23, 7, 12, 2),
  HONDA = c(2, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4),
  VW = c(4, 12, 7, 9, 5, 1),
  ROVER = c(1,3, 2, 4, 3, 1))
```

## A tidyverse solution

```
MY_CARS_SALES %>% 
  mutate(
    #VOLVO and VW score
    score_volvo = if_else(VOLVO < median(VOLVO),1,0),
    score_vw = if_else(VW < median(VW),1,0),
    #NISSAN and ROVER score
    score_nissan = if_else(NISSAN > median(NISSAN),1,0),
    score_rover = if_else(ROVER > median(ROVER),1,0),
    #SMOKE score
    score_smoke= if_else(SMOKE == 0,1,0),
    #PRICE score
    score_price = if_else(between(PRICE,6,16),1,0),
    #ANTIQUE score
    score_antique = if_else(ANTIQUE == "YES",1,0)
  ) %>% 
  #By row
  rowwise() %>% 
  #TOTAL score
  mutate(
    score_total = sum(c_across(score_volvo:score_antique))
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Few improvement suggestions -

- `ifelse(condition, 1, 0)` can be changed to `as.integer(condition)`.The latter is faster.
- Using `ifelse` on one column you don't need `sapply`. `ifelse` is vectorized so it can handle all the column value in one go. If there are more than one column that you want to check the condition for then you will need `sapply`.
- `'6:10'` is just a string. If you want to check for range of values use `6:10` or `6:16` as per the explanation in your question.
- When comparing more than one value (`6:16`) use `%in%` and not `==`.

Including all these changes in the answer, here is one `dplyr` approach -

```
library(dplyr)

bind_cols(MY_CARS_SALES, 
MY_CARS_SALES %>%
  mutate(across(c(VOLVO, VW), ~as.integer(.x < median(.x))),
         across(c(NISSAN, ROVER), ~as.integer(.x > median(.x))),
         SMOKE = as.integer(SMOKE == 0), 
         PRICE = as.integer(PRICE %in% 6:16), 
         ANTIQUE = as.integer(ANTIQUE == 'YES')) %>%
  transmute(NEWSCORE = rowSums(select(., VOLVO, VW, NISSAN, ROVER, SMOKE, PRICE, ANTIQUE))))

#  AGE ANTIQUE SMOKE PRICE TOYOTA VOLVO MERC MAZDA NISSAN HONDA VW ROVER NEWSCORE
#1   2     YES     2    45      5     7    2     9      1     2  4     1        3
#2   6      NO     0    40      9     6   12     2      3     8 12     3        3
#3   3      NO     1     6      8     4    1     4     23     4  7     2        3
#4   7      NO     3    22      9    10    7     6      7     5  9     4        2
#5   4     YES     0    16      2    12    8    13     12     1  5     3        6
#6   5      NO     1    10      3     8    3     6      2     4  1     1        2
```